# Python 2.7 exception do not handle unicode in python3 compatible code ('<exception str() failed>')

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, python-unicode

I'm trying to have a python2.7/3+ compatible code. And I'm struggling to handle raising a ValueError with a message in unicode correctly. I found very little results for "exception str() failed".

Here's the code:

```
from __future__ import (
    absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
)

import logging

from builtins import str
from future import standard_library

standard_library.install_aliases()

conf = {}
try:
    conf["key"]
except KeyError:
    msg = "Message"
    msg += " + ünicode"
    logging.warn(msg)
    raise ValueError(msg)
```

In python3 this is working as expected, but in python 2.7 as soon as `msg` contain unicode it gives:

```
WARNING:root:Message + ünicode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
ValueError: <exception str() failed>
```

Notice how the logging can handle the unicode string but not `ValueError`. What am I doing wrong ? How can I have a unicode error message in both python 2.7 and 3+ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to encode the msg convert it to string for Python 2, e.g.

```
from sys import version_info

if version_info.major == 2:
    raise ValueError(msg.encode('utf-8'))
elif version_info.major == 3:
    raise ValueError(msg)
else:
    raise YourException("not supported Python version")
```

Upate: Below is the workaround without importing any package if you only use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` without [python-future](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future) package:

```
if isinstance(msg, str):
   raise ValueError(msg)
else:
   raise ValueError(msg.encode('utf-8'))
```

Wait for patch from Python code level(e.g. six, future package) is nearly impossible as the problematic code is in C code level in [pythonrun.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c#L1314), it seems like `PyObject_Str(value)` execution for unicode string returned null

Comment: This is working in python2, but the message in python3 become `ValueError: b'Message + \xc3\xbcnicode'``

Comment: Then we could put a conditional clause. See my updated answer

Comment: This is a nice work around, I just wish there was a __future__ builtins for that.

Comment: I found that  the implementation for this code  is in C code level, it's nearly impossible to wait for a official fix or a workaround like six and future packages.  Please upvote and accept if it helps

Comment: The workaround is'nt working, because when using unicode_literal from __future__ and str from builtins, `isinstance(msg, str)` is true in python 2. I used the version_info one.

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas if you use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, the `msg` would be unicode.

Comment: yes, but I also imported `from builtins import str` thus `isinstance(msg, str)` is True in Python 2.7 : https://pastebin.com/hsGNB7hH

Comment: I knew, so I kept two solutions and explained in the answer.